# yaml using SnakeYaml

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

```
---
university: scsb
country: us

Entities:
 !Entity 
   name: john
   subjects:
    -math
    -English
    -C++
 !Entity
   name: mary
   subjects:
    -science
    -French
```

I am trying to load the above file into a map, with data under entities section to be mapped to collection of entity objects. Is this a correct yaml syntax as I get yaml parser error.

Answer (score 2):

I had more luck with the following:

```
---
university: scsb
country: us

Entities: {
 !Entity {
   name: john,
   subjects:
    -math
    -English
    -C++
 },
 !Entity {
   name: mary,
   subjects:
    -science
    -French
 }
}
```

Here is an example of using a custom tag (!dice) with SnakeYAML.  The full example is [here](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/source/browse/src/test/java/examples/DiceExampleTest.java).  It comes from the [SnakeYAML documentation](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#Constructors,_representers,_resolvers).

```
class DiceConstructor extends SafeConstructor {
    public DiceConstructor() {
        this.yamlConstructors.put(new Tag("!dice"), new ConstructDice());
    }

    private class ConstructDice extends AbstractConstruct {
        public Object construct(Node node) {
            String val = (String) constructScalar((ScalarNode) node);
            int position = val.indexOf('d');
            Integer a = new Integer(val.substring(0, position));
            Integer b = new Integer(val.substring(position + 1));
            return new Dice(a, b);
        }
    }
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void testConstructor() {
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new DiceConstructor());
    Object data = yaml.load("{initial hit points: !dice '8d4'}");
    Map<String, Dice> map = (Map<String, Dice>) data;
    assertEquals(new Dice(8, 4), map.get("initial hit points"));
}
```

Comment: Did you try the yaml data in the link you gave, that too seems to complain about syntax.

Comment: It was complaining about not recognizing the Entity datatype.  I assume that is defined elsewhere in your application.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but how do I define custom defined data types in yaml? I see references to !clarkevans.com,2002/graph/^shape in [yaml spec](http://yaml.org/spec/1.0/), is shape a java class in clarkevans.com package?

Comment: Typically custom type resolution is left up to the specific YAML implementation.  I haven't used SnakeYAML much but I will add a snippet from their documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it helped me a lot to have a custom tag in yaml for string concatenation.